# switching from ASP CHECK to INPUT CHECK and use find control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkbox

```
var chkBox = item.FindControl("chkbxDelete") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox;
```

finds the asp:CheckBox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID = "chkbxDelete" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MapID") %>'/>
```

but I need to change it to an `input` type. Is it possible to use `item.findcontrol` for a:

```
<input id="chkbxDelete" type="checkbox" value='<%#Eval("MapID") %>' class="chk" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just make sure to cast it to `HtmlInputCheckBox` which lives in `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` namespace:

```
HtmlInputCheckBox chkBox = item.FindControl("chkbxDelete") as HtmlInputCheckBox;
```